# assign a pandas dataframe NULL=0, non-NULLvalue=1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, null

In python 3.6 and pandas 0.19.0

There is a column "date"

```
date
2018-01-01
2018-01-02
2018-01-03

2018-01-05
```

I am trying to convert it into NULL=0, non-NULLvalue=1

```
date
1
1
1
0
1
```

The first step is to convert null into 0, which is easy

```
df['date'] = df['date'].fillna(value=0)
```

This gives me:

```
date
2018-01-01
2018-01-02
2018-01-03
0
2018-01-05
```

However, I am kinda stuck in converting non-zero values into 1.  pandas.set_values doesn't seem to be a good option here.

```
df['date']=df[(df.date != 0)] == "1"
```

The above doesn't seem to work as well with the error message:

```
TypeError: Could not compare ['1'] with block values
```

Any thoughts?  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date,errors='coerce').isnull().astype(int)
Out[862]: 
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    0
Name: date, dtype: int32
```

Or `df.date.isnull().astype(int)` (If the blank is `NaN` already)

Comment: Why not just `df.date.isna().astype(int)`?

Comment: pd.to_datetime(df.date,errors='coerce').isnull().astype(int)
                                                   ^                                         
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It seems like coerce is an invalid syntax @Wen in my environment

Comment: It looks to me "errors='coerce'=> make blank as 'NaN', and isnull() makes NaN "True" and else "Falase" and lastly astype(int) transform "True=1, false=0"?"